# Flutter / Dart Syntax - use of?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm stuck with understanding code of SharedPreferences in a Flutter App.

I have such code:

`upVotes = (prefs.getInt('upVotes') ?? 0) + 1`

What it means the `?? 0` part?

Thank you for your help

Comment: looks like null-coalesquing to me - if prefs has no getInt for upvotes assume 0.

Comment: the dupe handles ?. and ?? in its answer.

Answer (score 0):

It provides a default value i.e `0` if the `upVotes` is null.